# Get a field label instead of value using the api

Tags: api

I would like to retrieve both the value as well as the label from a custom field using the api, but it only seems possible to retrieve the value. 
I wonder if this is possible, would surely help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean a drop-down field? You then need to do another lookup on the OptionValue to get the label, e.g. from the api explorer:

```
    $result = civicrm_api3('OptionValue', 'get', [
      'return' => ["label"],
      'option_group_id' => "custom_marital_status",
      'value' => "S",
    ]);
```

gives you

```
"is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 1,
    "id": 866,
    "values": [
        {
            "id": "866",
            "label": "Single"
        }
    ]
```